# OpenERP logging to db

Tags: logging, odoo, openerp-6

Is there any way to logging errors to the database? 
(for example with a special server action) 
I found the res_log model, but unfortunately I have no idea how can I load it.
(actually I use openerp 6.1)

Comment: what's wrong with logging the errors to a file?

Comment: Full of garbage, log file is good for development, but I want to only the errors to db. Because of sometimes users much later reported the errors. From the db I can take easier a report in regulary and I can see the occurrence frequency.
But email can also be a right way.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this AFAIK in openerp 6.

You may want to backport the code from openerp 8 which does this.

See https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/netsvc.py#L74

Comment: hmmm, Do you know what is the res_log table? By default you can find it in tree view on Settings/Reporting/Audit Logs...but i cant find the use.
(I know, openERP 6 hava a default module (Audit Trail), and it is logs to this menu parent, but AFAIK is is a total other thing.)
In the worst case i will backport, so thank you your answer.

Comment: hmmm openerp 6 and odoo 8 have a very different architecture so, in my opinion no way to backport from this source, but it is possible to develop it to exception class.